# Broom Cannot handle nested lm model list when wrapped in either Trycatch or safely

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lm, broom

I've been trying to fit a linear model in a large dataset (~ 45 million groups of 3 points / group ). Owed to the sheer size of my dataset there are bound to be some cases where the model fit is off. Hence I am getting an error related to NAs in my lm model fit such as:

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases
```

The problem arises when I try to wrap lm around either TryCatch or Salely to catch and handle random errors during the fitting process

I tried several approaches so far. Here I'm giving you a dummy dataset:

To circumvent this error I have tried several methods. You'd argue that the easiest way is to do a grouped filter and exclude all datasets that are full of NAs (which I also tried to do but there are apparently some that have another sort of problem and cause my modelfits to hit errors).

Hence, since I want to have a robust flow that is applicable to maany types of data, I'm trying to write something that's quite generic and failsafe.

Moreover, I was hoping to use multidplyr for parallelization so I went the dplyr way. Here's the issue now. As soon as a wrap lm around either tryCatch or safely, even if I unnest later broom:tidy cannot handle the result. (which is a big bummer since it makes my life easy not having to code the lapply way all the time)

Case 1: Simple lm fit the standard way plus combine with broom. All is good

```
library(tidyverse)

df.h= tibble(
  hour  =  factor(c("1_1","1_1","1_1")),
  price =  c(3.235536,3.205588, 3.235930),
  wind  =  c(-2.302585, 3.871201, 5.123964)
)

dfHour = df.h2 %>% group_by(hour) %>%
  do(fitHour = lm(price ~ wind, data = .))

dfHourCoef = broom::tidy(dfHour, fitHour)
```

Introduce a failty dataset to produce an error in lm:

```
library(tidyverse)

df.h2= tibble(
  hour  =  factor(c("1_1","1_1","1_1","1_2","1_2","1_2")),
  price =  c(3.235536,3.205588, 3.235930, 3.235536,3.205588, 3.235930),
  wind  =  c(-2.302585, 3.871201, 5.123964, NA, NA, NA)
)


dfHour2 = df.h2 %>% group_by(hour) %>%
  do(fitHour = tryCatch( lm(myy ~ myx, data = . ), error= function(e){return("FAILURE")} ) ) %>%
  filter(!is.character(fitHour)) # Exploit the fact that all good outputs are 
                                 # a list while faulty output is a character
                                 # to perform filtering

# get the coefficients by group in a tidy data_frame
dfHourCoef2 = broom::tidy(dfHour2, fitHour)
```

This produces an error of the sort:

```
Error in .[[object]][[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Way Three: wrap into safely to catch error messages

```
library(tidyverse)

df.h2= tibble(
  hour  =  factor(c("1_1","1_1","1_1","1_2","1_2","1_2")),
  price =  c(3.235536,3.205588, 3.235930, 3.235536,3.205588, 3.235930),
  wind  =  c(-2.302585, 3.871201, 5.123964, NA, NA, NA)
)

test_dataset_lm <- df.h2 %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, droplevels) %>%    # this is used to exclude leftover
                                          # factor levels from previous 
                                          # processing in the flow
  group_by( hour ) %>%
  do(fitHour = safely(lm)(price ~ wind, data = .)) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  group_by(hour) %>%
  mutate(id = str_c("fitHour_", row_number() ) ) %>%  # Exploit that the 
                                                      # $error list is always 
                                                      # in the second position of every 
                                                      # output / modelfit trial
  spread(id, fitHour) %>%
  filter( fitHour_2 == "NULL" ) %>%
  rename(fitHour = fitHour_1) %>%
  select(-fitHour_2) %>% ungroup() %>%
  broom::tidy()
```

The latest approach is more computationally expensive and is expected to be much heavier to run in a very large dataset

The error this approach gives when combined with tidy() is:

```
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

I suspect that all error messages are a result of how tidy ( and glance ) expect the structure of the nested list produced, but I just can't figure out how to properly make it equivalent to the non-wraped versions.

Could you please help me understand the source of my issue?

Thanks!

Comment: The first chunk produces an error ```dfHourCoef = broom::tidy(dfHour, fitHour)>Error in broom::tidy(dfHour, fitHour) : object 'dfHour' not found```

Comment: Sorry, typo. Have to replace `df.h2` with `df.h` in the lm execution !

`dfHour = df.h2 %>% group_by(hour) %>%
  do(fitHour = lm(price ~ wind, data = .))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to fix the `safely` method

```
library(tidyverse)
df.h2 %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, droplevels) %>%    # this is used to exclude leftover
  # factor levels from previous 
  # processing in the flow
  group_by( hour ) %>%
  do(fitHour = safely(lm)(price ~ wind, data = .)) %>% 
  #Create a new column to check if 'result' in each fitHour element is missing/null
  mutate(Ind_null = map_lgl(fitHour['result'], is.null)) %>%
  filter(!Ind_null) %>%
  mutate(fit = list(tidy(fitHour[['result']]))) %>% 
  unnest(fit)

# A tibble: 2 x 6
   hour  term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
  <fct> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 1_1   (Intercept)  3.23      0.0162    200.    0.00319
2 1_1   wind        -0.00152   0.00411    -0.370 0.775
```

**Update:** (Shorter path) using `purrr::map_df`

```
lm_safe <- safely(lm)
df.h2 %>%
mutate_if(is.factor, droplevels) %>%  
split( .$hour ) %>% 
map_df(~tidy(lm_safe(price ~ wind, data = .)[['result']]), .id = 'hour')
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a great solution :) 

so essentially map_lgl maps the vector of lists? then the notation fitHour['result'] targets this nested list directly, you're basically "unnesting" the result ? 

Where can I read a bit more on nested lists and which functions handle them? ( how to target / handle etc )

Thanks again!

Comment: I target/test the _result_ component at each element of _fitHour_ and select this element if _result_ is not null, also we can do `map_lgl(fitHour[1], is.null)` as result always the first component. Here a simple example, `df.h2 %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, droplevels) %>%
    group_by( hour ) %>%
    do(fitHour = safely(lm)(price ~ wind, data = .)) -> lst`, explore `lst` in your counsle then do `map_lgl(lst$fitHour, ~is.null(.x[[1]]))` /  `map_lgl(lst$fitHour, ~is.null(.x[['result']]))` to see the output.

Comment: Jenny Bryan has a nice series of _purrr_ "a tidyverse package to handle and work with lists" tutorials at [the following link](https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/)

Comment: @MariosBarlas, please check my update which I think will reduce your computation time significantly.

Comment: Very interesting solution ! map_df will naturally skip empty dataframes of the $result nest as they are empty, right ? 

I benchmarked your solution on a parallelized code with a dataset of 1.8million points ( 600k fits ) and it runs 100% faster than the standard version. On an 8 core parallel cluster it gives 8min vs 14 for a complete run.

Comment: I'm glad it helps and indeed you have an interesting settings. Actually, `tidy` is the success key here, as `tidy` _handle_ the NULL results very efficiently by producing a tibble of 0X0 -try `tidy(NULL)`-, now try `df.h2 %>%
mutate_if(is.factor, droplevels) %>%  
split( .$hour ) %>% map(~tidy(lm_safe(price ~ wind, data = .)[['result']]), .id = 'hour')`, so `map_df` just combine or bind rows of these tibbles.